# WCF service and custom CA

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate, ca

I've created my custom Certificate Authority (CA) using openssl. Then I've created certificated using the previous one and the request from IIS. So now I have chain of certificates. Then I've bound the second one to my WCF service and every thing is fine. Then on client I've installed my CA certificate in Trusted Root Certification Authority to make it able to recognize my custom certificate.
My WCF service currently run on simple http connection.
Server side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="SyncWcfServices.MainServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="SyncWcfServices.MainService" behaviorConfiguration="SyncWcfServices.MainServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="/syncService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExtendedMaxSize" contract="SyncWcfServices.IMainService"></endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMainService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/SyncService/SyncService.svc"
binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMainService"
contract="SyncServiceReference.IMainService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMainService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So, I need to change this settings to support SSL connection. I've read a lot of post how to do it but there always using 2-way certification check that mean server must check client certificate and client must check server certificate. But I only want client to check server certificate using CA that I installed. And server will check with ordinary credentials (username, password) as it was before. I think that I have to change the security mode to Transport in both sides and server mex endpoint to mexHttpsBinding but what should I do next? Please help to resolve it. 
Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the correct way! So server side:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="SyncWcfServices.MainServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate
                    findValue = "*.mydomain.com"
                    storeLocation = "LocalMachine"
                    storeName = "My"
                    x509FindType = "FindBySubjectName"
                    />
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="SyncWcfServices.MainService" behaviorConfiguration="SyncWcfServices.MainServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExtendedMaxSize" contract="SyncWcfServices.IMainService"></endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8095/Design_Time_Addresses/SyncWcfServices/MainService/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client Side:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name = "ServiceCertificate">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode = "ChainTrust"/>
                    </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://localhost/SyncService/SyncService.svc"
         binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExtendedMaxSize"
         behaviorConfiguration = "ServiceCertificate"
         contract="SyncServiceReference.IMainService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMainService">
        </endpoint>             
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Hope it will help someone!
Also please look at "Programming WCF Services" (4th edition) book by Juval Lowy & Michael Montgomery. It's a great book!